# Converting streamlit library time input to milliseconds since epoch

Tags: python, datetime, time, streamlit

How to convert input from a streamlit time input [widget](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.time_input) to milliseconds since Unix Epoch? Time of the day comes from the time input widget and date have in the following string format

```
day = '20240325' #YYYYMMDD
time = st.time_input('Execution time', step=0:1:00)
print(time_in_ms_since_epoch)
```

Answer (score 1):

U need multipy total seconds with 1000 to get Unix Epoch. I wrote simply code I hope u can understand.

```
import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta


day = '20240325' #YYYYMMDD
time = st.time_input('Execution time', step=60)


date_time = day + f'{time}'
```

Conver date_time which is string to datetime.

```
date_time_res = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
```

Create epoch time.

```
epoch = datetime(2024, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0)
```

Unix Epoch part

```
time_in_ms_since_epoch = int((epoch-date_time_res).total_seconds() * 1000)

print(time_in_ms_since_epoch)
```